# Como fazer referência a outro HTML dos option na minha datalist?

Tags: html, html5

Eu tenho mais de 5.000 linhas para colocar como option dentro de uma datalist.
Eu já consegui deixar todos as minhas opções no formato correto, porém eu não queria deixar esse monte de linha no meu HTML princiapl.
Existe alguma maneira de colocar todos esses 5.000 option em outro HTML e fazer uma referência no meu HTML principal para que o datalist busque essas option lá nesse outro HTML?

No meu HTML principal eu fiz assim:

```
<datalist id="cidades">
                <option value="Rio de Janeiro"></option>
                <option value="Nova Iguaçu"></option>
                <option value="Niterói"></option>
                <option value="Belford Roxo"></option>
            </datalist>
```

Na minha outra HTML, eu fiz assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cidades Brasileiras</title>
</head>
<body>

<datalist id="cidades">
    <option value="Afonso Cláudio"></option>
    <option value="Água Doce do Norte"></option>
    <option value="Águia Branca"></option>
    <option value="Alegre"></option>
    <option value="Alfredo Chaves"></option>
    <option value="Alto Rio Novo"></option>
    <option value="Anchieta"></option>
    <option value="Apiacá"></option>
    <option value="Aracruz"></option>
    <option value="Atilio Vivacqua"></option>
...
```

Existe fazer isso aqui ou eu estou viajando demais:

```
<datalist URL="cidades.html#cidades">

</datalist>
```

Comment: Não sei ao certo mas as vezes com ajax vc consegue tratar isso

Comment: Deixar o código os options em JS ou iframe lhe atenderia? Tipo assim: https://repl.it/repls/SoupyAquaCopyleft ou https://repl.it/repls/BossyPowderblueOolanguage

Comment: Vou ver se essas soluções me atendem. Muito obrigado pela referência.

Comment: Funcionou Daniel, muito obrigado. Utilizei a solução do iFrame. Só preciso agora resolver a questão da estilização do campo, ele ficou bem distorcido depois de incorporar o iFrame. Mas valeu pela ajuda. Forte Abraço.